# Android - Use old play services version

Tags: android, version, google-play-services

I am trying to use Google play services `5.0.89` with Android Studio but it keeps saying he cannot find such version.
I am using this configuration :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:5.0.89'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:5.0.89'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:5.0.89'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:5.0.89'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:5.0.89'
```

But Android Studio keeps saying:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:5.0.89
```

And it does the same for each package listed above.
I checked into `Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/5.0.89/` and there are the following files into it:

```
play-services-5.0.89.aar
play-services-5.0.89.aar.md5
play-services-5.0.89.aar.sha1
play-services-5.0.89.pom
play-services-5.0.89.pom.md5
play-services-5.0.89.pom.sha1
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Google play services were not split until version 6.5 so you must use the generic dependency with everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the Google Play Services were not split at that time (you can see a single AAR in `Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/5.0.89/`).

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

Should work, but not the devision of it, like:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:5.0.89'
```

So using such old version forces you to use the full Google Play Services.

> From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: @tyczj Indeed. Added link to documentation.